# SBT: publish with pre-authenticated user fails

Tags: scala, sbt

I have this deployment phase with SBT:

```
publishTo := {
  publishMavenStyle := true
  if (isSnapshot.value)
    None
  else
    Some(Resolver.ssh("Maven Releases", "my.repository.com", "/here/and/there") as ("johndoe", ""))
}
```

However when I run this `sbt ... publish` I get the error:

```
java.io.IOException: Auth fail
    at org.apache.ivy.plugins.repository.ssh.SshCache.getSession(SshCache.java:338)
    at org.apache.ivy.plugins.repository.ssh.AbstractSshBasedRepository.getSession(AbstractSshBasedRepository.java:108)
```

actually the user `johndoe` is meant to run without passwords as on the server where sbt is run, it is already "authenticated" so no password is required. Is there any way to make it work with SBT?

Comment: Can you try without password ? So like this : `... as ("johndoe")` ?

Comment: I did it, but it opens a "ivy windows for authentication".